# Replacing an entire array in one fell swoop.

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array A of size 10 and another array B of size 5.

Both have the same elements, except array A has 5 more null elements. Can we replace the value of pointer A to pointer B like this:

```
arrayA = arrayB;
```

Comment: If you mean to merge the arrays, no. The code snippet will simply make arrayA and arrayB reference the same object.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but sounds like you might want System.arraycopy - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: now arrayA variable (stack) is referencing the arrayB object (heap), if arrayA object (heap) is no more referenced gc is gonna to erase arrayA object (heap), so doing this u lost reference to arrayA object

Comment: you mean arrayA will reference arrayB right?

Comment: put my nick @nachokk cause i dont notify. yeah that's is arrayA will reference arrayB , and u will lose reference to arrayA object

Comment: +1 for not misquoting Shakespeare, as many do, as "one *foul* swoop"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arrayA = arrayB;
```

Will make arrayA a reference to arrayB. There are no pointers in Java.

Comment: ok thanks i wasn't sure and i couldn't find anything on google strangely.

Answer (score 2):

No that would simply make the variable arrayA refer to arrayB (and lose its original reference to whatever array it was holding, data lost). You would need to copy it like so:

```
String[] a = ....
String[] b = new String[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0, a.length);
```

Note this copies a.length elements from index 0, the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a fell swoop is this one-liner:

```
System.arrayCopy(arrayA, 0, arrayB, 0, arrayB.length);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the run-time of `arrayCopy` O(n)?

Comment: @CardinalSystem Yes. It is O(n) to make a copy of an array, no matter which (reasonable) way you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change references for that. http://ideone.com/Rl3u4k

The snippet is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // array1 having three null elements
        String[] array1 = new String[]{ "hello", "world", "from", "array1", null, null, null };
        // array2 having no null elements
        String[] array2 = new String[]{ "hi", "this", "is", "array2" };

        // print array1
        for (String value : array1)
        {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        // swap values
        array1 = array2;

        // print array1 again
        for (String value : array1)
        {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
// before changing
hello
world
from
array1
null
null
null
// after changing reference
hi
this
is
array2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
public class SystemDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
      System.arraycopy(arr2, 5, arr1, 0, 5);

      for (int i : arr1) {
          System.out.println(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Then you will get a result:

```
6
7
8
9
10
```